# Google Cloud VPN over NAT

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, vpn, google-cloud-vpn

I'm trying to configure VPN between Google Cloud and a few on premise subnetworks hidden behind NAT. The problem is that I have only 1 external IP address and as I've said I'd like to create multiple VPN connections to few (~10) subnetworks which are hidden behind NAT. Is it possible?

Comment: You are leaving out a lot of details. There are many types of VPNs. For IpSec VPNs, NO. For software VPns such as OpenVPN, yes. For Site-to-Site, NO.

Comment: I don't think I'm leaving out any details. I'm pretty specific I'm talking about Google Cloud VPN (as the title suggests). AFAIU it uses ipsec, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: There are two sides to a VPN (Google cloud and your on-premises). Since you are using IpSec the answer is no. You need static public IP addresses to route the IpSec protocols. NAT gateways do not process the translation of IP protocols (ESP and AH) - at least I have never seen one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible.

GCP VPNs just support [one-to-one NAT](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/resources/troubleshooting#gateways_behind_nat) and this means a single Internal IP matching a single External IP.